# How to construct linear isomorphism between Quotient space and subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have Subspace $W = ((x,y,z) \in R^3 : x + y + z = 0)  \subset R^3$.
I want to construct linear isomorphism between Quotient space $R^3/W$ and subspace $((t,t,t):t \in R) \subset R^3$

As I know, Quotient space is defined as the set of all affine subsets of $R^3$, that are parallel to $W$. So in our case it will be planes.

But how do we construct the isomorphism between $R^3/W$ and subspace $((t,t,t):t \in R) \subset R^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $\mathbb R^3 = W^{\perp} \oplus W$ and that $W^{\perp} = \{(t,t,t) : t\in\mathbb R^3\}$.

In that way, one can write an element $x\in\mathbb R^3$ in the form $x=z_x+w_x$, with $z_x\in W^{\perp}$ and $w_x\in W$, where $z_x$ and $w_x$ are uniquely determined by $x$.

Define $\phi\colon \mathbb R^3/W \to W^{\perp}$ by 
$$\phi(x+W) = \phi((z_x+w_x)+W) = \phi(z_x+W) = z_x.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One question: how did you come with this equality: $\phi((z_x+w_x)+W) = \phi(z_x+W)$?

Comment: It is because $(z_x+w_x)+W=(z_x+W)+(w_x+W)$ and $w_x\in W$.